# Building MLPack from C++ source using CMake: is Julia required?

Tags: c++, cmake, mlpack

I am trying to build MLPack from its C++ source using CMake, and for some reason it is complaining that it can't find Julia.

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.14.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Julia not found (missing: JULIA_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version
  "0.7.0")

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? On the MLPack build instructions, there is no mention of Julia being a required package.

Thanks,
Amine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLPack has Julia bindings that are set to build by default (see the CMake [source](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/blob/08b128595bb50e12dacf7fd42c02dd58c41d8966/CMakeLists.txt#L20)). The CMake option is shown on the main GitHub [README](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/blob/master/README.md#4-building-mlpack-from-source) page. You can disable the Julia bindings build using the `BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS` variable:

```
cmake -DBUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS=OFF ..
```